# installing DoctrineFixturesBundle in symfony2.3.7

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to learn Symfony2. The problem I have is, when installing DoctrineFixturesBundle via updating composer.phar I get the following exception,

- Installing monolog/monolog (1.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%...

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://nodeload.github.com/Seldaek/monolog/zip/6225b22de9dcf36546be3a0
  b2fa8e3d986153f57" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

I have added "require": {
                       "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
                       } 
in composer.json

and the vendor\monolog folder goes empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*@dev"
```

in your composer.json file

if it is problem with monolog add following:

```
"monolog/monolog": "1.7.*@dev"
```